# can't add two decimal numbers using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, decimal

I am trying to add two decimal values but the returned sum is pure integer. What is wrong? I can't find it. any help will be welcome.

```
jQuery(".delivery-method #ship_select").change(function(){
    var cost = jQuery(this).val(); 
    jQuery("#delivery_cost").val(cost); //returns 20.00
    var tot = parseInt(cost) + parseInt(total); //total returns 71.96
});
```

With the code i am getting only `91` and not `91.96`

Comment: parseInt() kills your comma value

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use `parseFloat()` instead of `parseInt()`.

```
jQuery(".delivery-method #ship_select").change(function(){
    var cost = jQuery(this).val(); 
    jQuery("#delivery_cost").val(cost); //returns 20.00
    var tot = parseFloat(cost) + parseFloat(total); //total returns 71.96
});
```

Answer (score 7):

you have to use `parseFloat` Instead of `parseInt`

```
jQuery(".delivery-method #ship_select").change(function(){
      var cost = jQuery(this).val(); 
      jQuery("#delivery_cost").val(cost); //returns 20.00
     var tot = parseFloat(cost) + parseFloat(total); //total returns 71.96
 });
```

**Check Demo**:  http://jsfiddle.net/aDYhX/1/

Answer (score 2):

Use `parseFloat()` instead of `parseInt()`

```
var tot = parseFloat(cost) + parseFloat(total);
```

But, since you want to restrict to two decimal places strictly

```
function roundNumber(num, dec) {
   var result = Math.round(num*Math.pow(10,dec))/Math.pow(10,dec);
   return result;
}

var tot = roundNumber((cost+total), 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use parseFloat instead of parseInt and check.

Answer (score 1):

Integer arithmatic rounds down. Use `parseFloat` instead.